# Reading from SSL socket that has been closed by the server

Tags: java, sockets, ssl

I am trying to use a service (Apple's push notification) with a Java client.  Their documentation states that if there is an error in the data they have received, they will write some error codes to the socket and then close it.  (Nothing is returned until there is an error.)

I have an SSLSocket with input and output streams.  My code writes to the output stream until it gets a broken pipe exception, then tries to read from the input stream.  I never see any data returned - it's as if they have closed the socket without writing the promised error code.

Is there something in the Java SSLSocket implementation that makes it impossible to read from a socket (i.e. the result of getInputStream()) after a broken pipe exception has happened on the output stream?  I am not shutting down the socket input or output, or anything like that.

Any other ideas?

My code looks something like this:

```
SSLSocket socket = createMyConnectionToServer();

OutputStream outputStream = socket.getOutputStream();
InputStream inputStream = socket.getInputStream();
try {
    while (true) {
        outputStream.write(someStuff); // fails with broken pipe the second time
        outputStream.flush();
    }
} catch (SocketException ex) {
    while (true) {
        int b = inputStream.read();
        if (b == -1)
            break
        System.out.println("response " + b); // this never happens
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Writing until a broken pipe exception is already wrong. Once it's broken you can neither read nor write. This has nothing to with SSL: a plaintext socket would behave the same way. You may need a separate reading thread.

Comment: The reason I though this would work is that Apple's docs say "If you send a notification that is malformed or otherwise unintelligible, APNs returns an error-response packet and closes the connection.".  I assumed that if they write and then close, I would be able to read what they have written.  A second thread would introduce a race condition but might work sometimes.

Comment: You can, but you have to read the response *before* writing to the point of breaking the pipe. I must say I've never been able to make head or tail of Apple's intention with this protocol. They should provide an acknowledgement for everything, not just for mistakes.

Comment: Clearly they want to minimize load on their servers.  They could fix their protocol by (1) writing a confirmation message for good packets,  or, probably more importantly, (2) write the error message and wait for the sender to close the socket.  After an error they can ignore all following data because the sender should be able to back up to the first message after the bad one.

Comment: Agreed. The problem is that the protocol makes the client end very hard to implement. You need a thread that is always reading, looking for errors, and you need it to be able to stop or signal the writing side of things when there's an error. And in the nature of TCP the writing side can easily get a few writes ahead of the one that caused the error, which gives you transactional/rollback problems.